# What are the options of getting from Dresden (Germany) to Český Krumlov (Czech Republic)?

Tags: air-travel, trains, germany, buses, czech-republic

My husband and I are going to travel from Dresden to Český Krumlov the last week of December. We searched for train and bus but the train option seems to be unavailable between the two cities (https://www.bahn.de/i/view/USA/en/index.shtml) and the bus option (http://www.goeuro.com/travel-search2/results/418335442/bus) sounds to be unnecessarily long since the bus first travels to Prague and then it gets to Český Krumlov from Prague after an hour. What are other options?

Comment: What do you mean, unavailable? The bahn.de site does show me train options (with transfers at least in Prague and České Budějovice). And considering that Prague is pretty much directly between the two places, it doesn't seem like a large detour to me. For more options (including bus/train combinations), consider using http://idos.cz.

Comment: @svick it does have options but doesn't sell online tickets for the specific date(Dec 27th) it only has the option that they send you the booked tickets by mail.

Comment: There are relatively cheap buses (~20 EUR per person) available which drive there with a change in Prague. Try busliniensuche.de (https://www.busliniensuche.de/suche/?From=Dresden&To=Český+Krumlov&When=2016-12-27&WhenReturn=&Passengers=1&ShowRidesharing=true&Radius=15000&WithChangeover=true) The tickets can almost always be printed or shown on a smartphone.

Comment: I went through Dresden to Prague with a stopover and then to Budejovice by train. That town is worth a day, especially if you're interested in beer. From there they have busses that take about half an hour and cost something like 4 EUR round trip per person, including a bottle of water and they have on-board movies. The bus station in Budweis is on top of the shopping mall, when you get out of the train station to your left.

Comment: Another option - https://shop.flixbus.de/search?adults=1&children=0&bikes=0&departureStation=&arrivalStation=&departureCity=355&arrivalCity=7838&rideDate=27.12.2016&oneway=&backRideDate=07.12.2016&adults=&children=&bikes=&_locale=de&form_build_id=form-USjV91P114fu2V_gVO9f0Pj-XwYi46MyGYqeVjVNzus&form_id=fb_search_form_main&_ga=1.12768243.575191800.1476710541

Comment: Assuming you can return back to Dresden, just rent a car. Traveling by public transport during the end of December is miserable.

Answer (score 6):

You can buy electronic tickets from Dresden to Český Krumlov from the Czech Railway's ["eShop"](https://www.cd.cz/eshop/). The ticket will be sent to your e-mail address as a PDF file and costs CZK 1087 (appr. €40.20) for a full-price refundable ticket or CZK 662 (appr. €24.50) if you can make use of the "First Minute Europa" offer (must be bought at least 3 days in advance, limited number of tickets, non-refundable, bound to a specific connection). Currently, "First Minute Europa" tickets are still available for most connections on December 27th.

Travel time by train is between 5:45h and 6:00h and I sincerely doubt that you will find a faster connection using public transport. If you rent a car, Google Maps estimates 4 hours for the ride, but expect steep surcharges for one-way international rentals unless you are also going back to Dresden.

Answer (score 3):

Trains *are* available, but neither the Czech Railway company, nor the German "Deutsche Bahn" are able to give you a price quote online. Both pages list reasonable train connections and show that you either have to (1) visit a ticket office, or (2) call to buy a ticket (or two). Note that calling does not mean that the ticket will be sent by post - rather you get a pickup code for the ticket vending machines at the train station in Dresden (or elsewhere).

There is a tool (whose link I cannot post) for finding price estimations for European Rail journeys. It seems to be 39,40 Euro one-way, but at German Railway counters, it may be more, as they use their own tariff for the German part of the journey. According to the [EuroSpezial offer page](https://www.bahn.de/p/view/angebot/sparpreis-europa/tschechien.shtml), there may also be the possibility to get a saver's fare (which is cheaper but inflexible), but you cannot check this online as it seems.

Comment: Why can't you post the link?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas It's an internal link that will most likely quickly stop to work once google finds it well (which would eventually happen if I post it here). Also, the prices only seem to be accurate when buying the ticket in the Czech republic - loco2.com sells the route for 75 British pounds (flexible ticket), which is a lot more.